# reverse using of Thread.join() in java

Tags: java

I know that I can use the following to have thread B waiting for  thread A to finish before proceeding:

```
class A extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        ....
    }
}
class B extends Thread{
    private Thread someThread;
    B(Thread t){
        someThread=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        someThread.join();
        ...//then proceed
    }
}
```

But how can I do this in the `run()` of `A` to call `B` and then wait it finish before proceeding? That is, I want something like

```
class A extends Thread{
    private Thread someThread;
    B(Thread t){
        someThread=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        //*how to start B and wait it finish?
        ...//then proceed
    }
}
class B extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If both threads are waiting for the other to complete then you have a classic deadlock. This design is highly suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, a simpler solution would be to start `B` first, then `b.join();`, and do the same for `A` in the client code:

```
b.start();
b.join();
a.start();
a.join();
```

There is no sense in starting a thread for it to just fire up and join on another tread before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Same deal:

```
class A extends Thread{
    private Thread someThread;
    A(Thread t){
        someThread=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        someThread.start();
        someThread.join();
        // proceed
    }
}
class B extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misplaced a constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
class A extends Thread{

    private Thread someThread;

    B(Thread t){
        someThread=t;
    }
    public void run(){
        someThread.join()
        //do stuff
    }
}

class B extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread b = new B();
b.start();
b.join();
```

But why would you want to? The idea of threads is to do things in parallel. Why would you start a thread and immediately wait for it to finish? Just execute the stuff from B in place in A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join() to wait for any thread.

```
final Thread a = Thread.currentThread();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do something
        a.join();
        // calling thread finished.
    }
 }).start();
 // do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below example for how to reverse execute the thread.?

We can use join method for this case.

```
    package interview.thread;
     public class RevarseThreadExcute {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 3 =" + i);

                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               try {
                t3.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 2 =" + i);

                }
            }
        });

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    t3.join();
                    t2.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1 =" + i);

                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }


}
```

outpot:

```
Thread 3 =0
Thread 3 =1
Thread 3 =2
Thread 3 =3
Thread 3 =4
Thread 3 =5
Thread 3 =6
Thread 3 =7
Thread 3 =8
Thread 3 =9
Thread 2 =0
Thread 2 =1
Thread 2 =2
Thread 2 =3
Thread 2 =4
Thread 2 =5
Thread 2 =6
Thread 2 =7
Thread 2 =8
Thread 2 =9
Thread 1 =0
Thread 1 =1
Thread 1 =2
Thread 1 =3
Thread 1 =4
Thread 1 =5
Thread 1 =6
Thread 1 =7
Thread 1 =8
Thread 1 =9
```